# jQuery UI Sortable with connected lists which one is using float elements

Tags: jquery, css-float, jquery-ui-sortable

I have problem with jQuery UI Sortable when the first list is normal vertical and the second one is horizontal using float li elements. Everything is fine when I drop the element into. But when Im holding the element Im not able remove/add the float CSS style.

**Here is a demonstration:** [jsfiddle.net/dsdjj9xd/3](http://jsfiddle.net/dsdjj9xd/3/).

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thank you.

```
<div class="jersey-select">
                <div class="left-jersey-select">
                    <ul class="sortable-jersey" id="active">
                            <li class="ui-state-default active" id="10">
                                <span class="cursor"></span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li class="ui-state-default active" id="6">
                                <span class="cursor"></span>                                 
                            </li>                            
                            <li class="ui-state-default active" id="7">
                                <span class="cursor"></span>                                  
                            </li>                            
                            <li class="ui-state-default active" id="13">
                                <span class="cursor"></span>                             
                            </li>                            
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="right-jersey-select">
                    <ul class="sortable-jersey" id="available">
                        <li class="ui-state-default available" id="8">
                            <span class="cursor"></span>
                        </li>                            
                        <li class="ui-state-default available" id="30">
                            <span class="cursor"></span>                              
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default available" id="31">
                            <span class="cursor"></span>                              
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default available" id="32">
                            <span class="cursor"></span>                              
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default available" id="33">
                            <span class="cursor"></span>                              
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default available" id="37">
                            <span class="cursor"></span>                              
                        </li>
                        <br style="clear: both">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$( ".sortable-jersey" ).sortable({        
    connectWith: ".sortable-jersey",
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {            
    },
    over: function( event, ui ) {
        var to = $(this).attr("id");
        if (to == 'available') { 
            $(ui.item).removeClass('active');
            $(ui.item).addClass('available');
            $(ui.item).css('width', '154px');
            $(ui.item).children("span.colorpicker").addClass('display_none');
        } else if (to == 'active') {
            $(ui.item).removeClass('available');
            $(ui.item).addClass('active');
            $(ui.item).css('width', '220px');
            $(ui.item).children("span.colorpicker").removeClass('display_none');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

CSS:

```
.jersey-left {
    width: 535px; margin: 5px;
}

.left-jersey-select {
    width: 230px; float: left;
}

.jersey-select {

}

.right-jersey-select {
    width: 500px; float: right;
}

.sortable-jersey {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 75px;
    background: #F0F0F0;    
}

.sortable-jersey li.active {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 220px;
}

.sortable-jersey li.available {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 154px;
}

.sortable-jersey li span {
    margin: 30px 0 0 5px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("/images/icons/cursor.png");
    position: absolute;
    background: red;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out, If I set in all lists float: left everything works properly. Because i can use float also if I want to have vertical list.